# drawableStart in button doesn't scale correctly

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button

I have a `drawableStart` icon drawable in my `Button` below but it doesn't scale correctly. What can i do to correct this?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/show_in_map_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_details_button"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/location_btn"
    android:drawableTint="@android:color/white"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
    android:paddingStart="15dp"
    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
    android:text="@string/show_in_map_button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/place_description" />
```

P.S: I've seen a few posts regarding this issue that attempted to solve it in code using `ScaleDrawable`, but that didn't work for me.

[image: result]

Comment: Are you okay to make **custom Button** for this? I had the same issue in the past and ended up creating custom button for the same.

Comment: How do u want the buton and the drawable to be displayed inside on it??? post a screenshot or a description. SS would be great!

Comment: @JeelVankhede I've never tried that before so why not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an old approach that works for me.

I simply create bounds and set it to my button. This way any drawable I attach to my drawable takes the dimension of the bounds.

```
drawable.bounds = Rect(0, 0, 80, 80) // in this case, the drawable is going to be 80 x 80
button.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null)
```

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Comment: This did it. Just had to use drawable.setBounds(new Rect(0,0,80,80)); Thanks for the help, this will come in handy later on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this, You can scale your drawable like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/logo"
    android:scaleGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:scaleHeight="80%"
    android:scaleWidth="80%" />
```

You can also scale your drawable like this

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: Do i need to use it somewhere in code for it to take effect and if so where?

Comment: open the location_btn drawable and add android:scaleHeight="80%"
    android:scaleWidth="80%" this to scale it

Comment: Ok, if the drawable is not a svg then you can just add this to your above code or try other scaleType available
 android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: I don't think `android:scaleType="fitXY"` works in a `Button`, i tried it earlier as a solution on another post but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to wrap your resource in a drawable and define the height and width there and then use that drawable in your `android:drawableStart` attribute. This only works from API 23 and above, but it won't crash your app on API 21 for example though. You can take a look at the example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/location_btn"
      android:width="@dimen/icon_size"
      android:height="@dimen/icon_size" />

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use drawable padding also.

Answer (score 0):

To have *drawable* of your custom size in `Button` or `TextView`, you can create custom class like below with some stylable attributes:

1. create **attrs.xml** file in **res -> values** folder and create *styleable* like below:

   ```
   <resources>
       <declare-styleable name="DrawableButton">
           <attr name="drawableSize" format="dimension" />
           <attr name="drawableScale" format="float" />
       </declare-styleable>
   </resources>
   ```
2. Then create class named `DrawableButton` like below:

   ```
   class DrawableButton : AppCompatButton {
       internal var drawableSize: Float? = null
       internal var drawableScale: Float = 1F

       constructor(context: Context?) : this(context, null)

       constructor(context: Context?, attr: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attr, android.R.style.Widget_Button)

       constructor(context: Context?, attr: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attr, defStyle) {
           loadAttrs(context, attr)
           initDrawablesForResize()
       }

       private fun loadAttrs(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) {
           if (context != null && attrs != null) {
               val typedArray: TypedArray? = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DrawableButton, 0, 0)
               typedArray?.let { arr ->
                   for (index in 0 until arr.indexCount) {
                       assignValueToVariables(arr, index)
                   }
               }
               typedArray?.recycle()
           }
       }

       private fun assignValueToVariables(arr: TypedArray, index: Int) {
           val resourceId = arr.getIndex(index)
           when (resourceId) {
               R.styleable.DrawableButton_drawableSize -> {
                   drawableSize = arr.getDimension(resourceId, Math.min(measuredHeight, measuredWidth).toFloat())
               }
               R.styleable.DrawableButton_drawableScale -> {
                   drawableScale = arr.getFloat(resourceId, 1F)
               }
               else -> {
                   // Left out because "Unused"
               }
           }
       }

       private fun initDrawablesForResize() {
           val size = compoundDrawablesRelative.size
           val drawableList = ArrayList<Drawable?>(size)
           for (index in 0 until size) {
               val drawable = compoundDrawablesRelative[index]
               if (drawable != null) {
                   if (drawableSize == null) {
                       drawableSize = Math.min(drawable.intrinsicHeight.times(drawableScale), drawable.intrinsicWidth.times(drawableScale))
                   }
                   drawable.setBounds(
                       0,
                       0,
                       drawableSize!!.toInt(),
                       drawableSize!!.toInt()
                   )
                   drawableList.add(index, drawable)
               } else {
                   drawableList.add(index, null)
               }
           }
           this.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(drawableList[0], drawableList[1], drawableList[2], drawableList[3])
       }

       override fun performClick(): Boolean {
           super.performClick()
           return true
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Rebuild the project** once and now you're ready to use this `DrawableButton` class in your xml file like below:

   ```
   <your_package_name_where_this_class_is.DrawableButton
       android:id="@+id/show_in_map_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
       android:background="@drawable/round_details_button"
       android:drawableStart="@drawable/location_btn"
       android:drawableTint="@android:color/white"
       android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
       android:paddingStart="15dp"
       android:paddingEnd="15dp"
       android:text="@string/show_in_map_button"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       android:textSize="14sp"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/place_description" />
   ```

Now you can use **`drawableSize`** or **`drawableScale`** attributes from **`app:`** or other custom namespace to scale your drawables in *`drawableStart`, `drawableEnd`, `drawableTop` or `drawableBottom`*. It works with both **vectors** as well as **raster images**.

> Note : *It doesn't work with drawableLeft & drawableRight, due to method `setCompoundDrawablesRelative()` which uses start and end attrs for drawables. To work with left and right drawables replace this method with `setCompoundDrawables()` method.*